# Can "with" be used with "invoice"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

After buying something, I request seller to make sales invoice. But he said that he couldn't give invoice. Upon this can say the sentence below by using "with" in this way?

> I always buy with invoice.

I just wonder if "with" can be used in this way .

Comment: The answer below notes that "invoice" does not seem to the correct word in this context.  Could you clarify?  Did you mean to use "receipt"?

Comment: I ask the sales person to give me a receipt. Invoices are bills. Not a receipts.

Answer (score 1):

> I always buy with an invoice

is grammatical (notice that the article is needed to make the sentence grammatical). But it is rather odd.

You were asking for a receipt. "Invoice" is not the technically correct word. An invoice specifies what is being sold at what amount and the total due, but it does not acknowledge that payment has been made as does a receipt. Admittedly, it is frequently true, particularly in retail stores, that the same document acts as both invoice and receipt, but such a combined document is typically called a receipt or a sales receipt.

Answer (score -1):

I think you meant to say:

> I always get receipts while shopping.

Your sentence is grammatically correct, but the meaning is not the one you want.